# Console output from worker nodes to a file in Spark cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, cluster-mode

I am running a `pyspark` script using `spark-submit`. The job runs succesfully.

Now I am trying to collect console output of this job to a file like below.

`spark-submit in yarn-client mode`

```
spark-submit --master yarn-client --num-executors 5 --executor-cores 5 --driver-memory 5G --executor-memory 10G --files /usr/hdp/current/spark-client/conf/hive-site.xml --jars /usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar,/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar --py-files customer_profile/customer_helper.py#customer_helper.py,customer_profile/customer_json.json customer_profile/customer.py  > /home/$USER/logs/customer_2018_10_26 2>&1
```

I am able to redirect all the console output written to the file `/home/$USER/logs/customer_2018_10_26` includes all `loglevels and any stacktrace errors`

`spark-submit in yarn-cluster mode`

```
spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --num-executors 5 --executor-cores 5 --driver-memory 5G --executor-memory 10G --files /usr/hdp/current/spark-client/conf/hive-site.xml --jars /usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar,/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar --py-files customer_profile/customer_helper.py#customer_helper.py,customer_profile/customer_json.json customer_profile/customer.py  > /home/$USER/logs/customer_2018_10_26 2>&1
```

USing `yarn-cluster` mode I am unable to redirect console output written to the file `/home/$USER/logs/customer_2018_10_26`.

The problem is if my job fails in `yarn-client` mode I can go to file `/home/$USER/logs/customer_2018_10_26` and easily look for the errors.

But if my job fails in `yarn-cluster` mode then I am not getting the stack trace to be copied to the file `/home/$USER/logs/customer_2018_10_26`. The only way I can debug the error is using `yarn logs`.

I would like to avoid using the `yarn logs` option Instead I want to see the `error stack trace` in the file `/home/$USER/logs/customer_2018_10_26` itself while using `yarn-cluster` mode.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Are you using YARN log aggregation? Even if you are, logs only go to a specific folder on HDFS that the Spark History Server can read, not into the user directory for those that ran the job... Besides that, you're only capturing the driver output, not the executors

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes I have `Yarn log aggregation` enabled. and I do capture the executors output as well Please let me know

Comment: How are you getting the executor logs? I don't think `> output.log` captures that

Comment: @cricket_007 `> output.log` this doesn't get the executor logs. It gets only the executor logs. How do I get the executor logs? Could you please help me in this regards

Comment: You can't get it from `spark-submit` output, unfortunately. That's where YARN log aggregation comes in. That aggregation is not immediate, and it really only helps to get it to the Spark History Server. Other solutions exist that are outside of YARN/Spark such as FIlebeat or Fluentd to watch the logs on the actual executor machines and send them elsewhere, such as Elasticsearch for easier gathering